# tableview image not getting refreshed

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate i am trying to load different images into a custom cell depending on which array (detailViewListLoadMore) is being loaded into the table. The array contains annotation objects.

however the images dont seem to refresh, they seem to be the same as the last array unless i scroll down and then they are correct, its like they are being pre loaded from the last array.

here is my method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//set up custom table cell
static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";

//reuse the custom cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier]; 

//setup custom cell
if (cell == nil) {

    //load custom cell from nib
    NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomDetailViewCell"
                                                      owner:self
                                                    options:nil];

    if ([nibArray count] > 0)
        cell = self.detailCell;
    else
        NSLog(@"failed to load CustomDetailViewCell nib file");

} 

//configure the cell row
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

//create temp cell lable strings
NSString *headingString, *detailString, *subDetailString, *imageString;
UIImage *cellDistanceImage;

//create temp annotation object
Annotation *tempAnnotationObj = [detailViewListLoadMore objectAtIndex:row];            

if (tempAnnotationObj.type == @"one")
    cellDistanceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnnotationOne.png"];
else if (tempAnnotationObj.type == @"two")
    cellDistanceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnnotationTwo.png"];
else if (tempAnnotationObj.type == @"three")
    cellDistanceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AnnotationThree.png"];

}

//set table cell strings
headingString = tempAnnotationObj.streetName;
detailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No of Bays: %@",tempAnnotationObj.bays];
        subDetailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@m",tempAnnotationObj.distance];           

//update heading label
UILabel *headingLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
headingLabel.text = headingString;

//update detail label
UILabel *detailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
detailLabel.text = detailString;

//update sub detail label
UILabel *subDetailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
subDetailLabel.text = subDetailString;    

//set appropriate distance image
[self.detailCellImage setImage:cellDistanceImage];

return cell;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: first of all please use [tempAnnotationObj.type isEqualToString:@"three"] instead of ==, it is a wrong method to compare NSStrings. then you can check out which one of the condition is getting selected in your if/elseif case.

Comment: there is one extra closing brace '}'. is there a few lines missing in sample code?

Comment: yeah, i didnt post it all. just the relevant bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seemed to work it out using this....

```
UIImageView *anImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
[anImageView setImage:cellDistanceImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `[tableView reloadData];` into the method that changes tableView's data source?

Answer (score 0):

why you have set

```
//set appropriate distance image
[self.detailCellImage setImage:cellDistanceImage];
```

with self if you want to set image on cell? i think it should be

> cell.detailCellImage

Comment: because for the cell image i created a UIImageView and linked it up in the IB. if i change it to cell i get the error "property 'detailCellImage' not found on object of type "UITableViewCell *"

Comment: oh.. so you are keeping an imageview in your class and the single imageview is showing up on all cells?

Comment: i dont know why i set it up like that, but i dont want it keeping in my class. i have changed it to... UIImageView *anImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    [anImageView setImage:cellDistanceImage];. seems to work fine, dont know why i didnt do it like this before

Comment: 90% chances of the problem are related to not calling [tableView reloadData] after updating the dataSource. please check it atleast 4 times that reloadData is being called from somewhere when you update the data source. if still the problem cannot be corrected. there is problem at some other part of your code which is less likely.

Comment: cheers, i will check. I wonder if this issue also applies to an activity indicator i have on the last cell of the table to load more rows. however it works when pressed once then disappears?